# In R, how to get the whole command line into the sys.call() of a binary operator?

Tags: r, operators, operator-overloading, new-operator

I wrote a binary operator function for R (i.e. one with a name like `%X%` so that instead of having to type `%X%(a,b)` I can use the more convenient syntax `a %X% b`. My goal is to have a wrapper for `<-` that does things like log what was done to objects in that environment and check for a 'protected' attribute which would warn the user before overwriting that object.

All of this works, except that if I try do do something like `a %X% b + c` inside the function all you see is `a %X% b` _and that is also all it does; a gets assigned the value of b and c is completely ignored. `a %X% (b + c)` works and so does `%X%(a, b + c)` but the whole point of writing this as a binary operator is to avoid parentheses.

If I overwrite `<-`, its `sys.call()` sees everything to the left and right of it. Why does mine only see only the adjacent names from the command line?

Here is code that replicates this problem:

```
`%X%` <- function(...){
    print(deparse(sys.call()));
}

a %X% 3 + 1:10;
```

The desired result is "a %X% 3 + 1:10"
The observed result is "a %X% 3"

Thanks.

Comment: Odd; when I run the code (R 2.15.1) I get `Error in a %X% 3 + 1:10 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: @DavidRobinson, the error comes from the `+` operator when attempting to sum the output of `a %X% 3` of type character with `1:10` of type numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose there is no way to lower the precedence of a custom operator. However, I think I found a cheesy workaround: *I can name my operator* `<<-`

I don't really understand how `<-` dispatching works, and there must be dozens for different object-specific methods of `<-` (none of which show up in `methods(`<-`)`. All I know is that when I override `<-` all kinds of stuff breaks.

However, `<<-` has a precedence close to that of `<-`, and it's not particularly useful because for the occasional case where you really do need to write a global variable from inside a function or a loop, you can just use `.GlobalEnv[['foo']] <- bar` or `assign('foo',bar,env=.GlobalEnv)`.

Besides, since I'm only attempting to log and write-protect objects in .GlobalEnv in the first place, the new meaning I'm assigning to `<<-` is even somewhat consistent with the original one.

Answer (score 6):

This has to do with operator precedence, see `?Syntax` for more help. It says that special operators (`%any%`) like the one you are trying to define  have higher precedence than the binary `+`, so there is no other way (AFAIK) for you than to use parenthesis and do `a %X% (b + c)`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: then how does `<-`/`=` work? I take it it's not a binary operator

Comment: @DavidRobinson, `<-` and `=` are binary operators, with very low precedence, see `?Syntax`.