# Is there a way for an R function to tell if it's being called from a `for` or `while` loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, scope, while-loop

The title of the question pretty much says it: is there a way for an R function to find out if it is being called directly or from inside a `for` or `while` loop? `sys.frame(0)` or `parent.frame(1)` returns `.GlobalEnv` whether the function was called directly or from inside one of those loops. So, is there some other way?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the context of this problem is important to give good advice.  What is your purpose?  What are you attempting to do?

Comment: I've written a wrapper function for `<<-` that keeps a log changes to global objects along with timestamps (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813599/in-r-how-to-get-the-whole-command-line-into-the-sys-call-of-a-binary-operator). That works great. Now, I'd like it to notice when it's being called from a loop and instead of logging e.g. `foo[ii] <<- mean(bar[ii+1,])` dozens of times, log just one such operation and note that it was a loop. Or maybe log it, but substitute in the value of `ii` on each cycle. Perhaps there is a way to programmatically peek at history?

Comment: @f1r3br4nd The only thing that comes to mind is `?loadhistory`. I know there are some questions on SO with people hacking their histories, you might consider poking around for those.

Comment: have you looked at the [track](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/track/index.html) and [SOAR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SOAR/index.html) packages on CRAN, if tracking objects is what you intend on doing?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a definitive answer, but I think your solution will be to look at the `sys.status`, specifically the `sys.parents`. The second example is for when the function is called within another function, and within a loop. Not sure how you differentiate this without knowing explicitly.

```
test <- function() sys.status()

for(i in 1:2){
  print(test())
 }


## $sys.calls
## $sys.calls[[1]]
## print(test())
## 
## $sys.calls[[2]]
## test()
## 
## $sys.calls[[3]]
## sys.status()
## 
##
## $sys.parents
## [1] 0 0 2
##
## $sys.frames
## $sys.frames[[1]]
## <environment: 0x0479a1c8>
##
## $sys.frames[[2]]
## <environment: 0x0479a2fc>
##
## $sys.frames[[3]]
## <environment: 0x0479a334>
##
##
## $sys.calls
## $sys.calls[[1]]
## print(test())
##
## $sys.calls[[2]]
## test()
## 
## $sys.calls[[3]]
## sys.status()
##
##
## $sys.parents
## [1] 0 0 2
## 
## $sys.frames
## $sys.frames[[1]]
## <environment: 0x047993cc>
## 
## $sys.frames[[2]]
## <environment: 0x04799570>

## $sys.frames[[3]]
## <environment: 0x047995a8>
```

and

```
test()

## $sys.calls
## $sys.calls[[1]]
## test()
## 
## $sys.calls[[2]]
## sys.status()
## 
## 
## $sys.parents
## [1] 0 1
## 
## $sys.frames
## $sys.frames[[1]]
## <environment: 0x04775500>
##   
##   $sys.frames[[2]]
## <environment: 0x04775538>
```

and

```
test_sq <- function() test()

for(i in 1:2){
  print(test_sq())
 }

## $sys.calls
## $sys.calls[[1]]
## print(test_sq())
## 
## $sys.calls[[2]]
## test_sq()
## 
## $sys.calls[[3]]
## test()
## 
## $sys.calls[[4]]
## sys.status()
## 
## 
## $sys.parents
## [1] 0 0 2 3
## 
## $sys.frames
## $sys.frames[[1]]
## <environment: 0x04766c60>
##   
##   $sys.frames[[2]]
## <environment: 0x04766dcc>
##   
##   $sys.frames[[3]]
## <environment: 0x04766e04>
##   
##   $sys.frames[[4]]
## <environment: 0x04766e3c>
##   
##   
##   $sys.calls
## $sys.calls[[1]]
## print(test_sq())
## 
## $sys.calls[[2]]
## test_sq()
## 
## $sys.calls[[3]]
## test()
## 
## $sys.calls[[4]]
## sys.status()
## 
## 
## $sys.parents
## [1] 0 0 2 3
## 
## $sys.frames
## $sys.frames[[1]]
## <environment: 0x04765ac8>
##   
##   $sys.frames[[2]]
## <environment: 0x04765c34>
##   
##   $sys.frames[[3]]
## <environment: 0x04765c6c>
##   
##   $sys.frames[[4]]
## <environment: 0x04765d30>
```

and

```
test_sq()


## $sys.calls
## $sys.calls[[1]]
## test_sq()
## 
## $sys.calls[[2]]
## test()
## 
## $sys.calls[[3]]
## sys.status()
## 
## 
## $sys.parents
## [1] 0 1 2
## 
## $sys.frames
## $sys.frames[[1]]
## <environment: 0x0475ce40>
##   
##   $sys.frames[[2]]
## <environment: 0x0475cee8>
##   
##   $sys.frames[[3]]
## <environment: 0x0475cf20>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `for` doesn't appear in `sys.calls` normally. While its a bit of a hack, you can actually override `for`, causing it to be included:

```
`for` = function(iter, vec, expr) eval.parent(replace(sys.call(), 1, list(.Primitive('for'))))
in.for = function() '`for`' %in% lapply(sys.calls(), `[[`, 1)
my.fun = function() { print('before'); print(in.for()); print('after') }

my.fun()
# [1] "before"
# [1] FALSE
# [1] "after"
for (x in 1) my.fun()
# [1] "before"
# [1] TRUE
# [1] "after"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a optional parameter for example

```
Blah <- function(Param1, OptionalParam = 0){
    if(OptionalParam == 1){
        #Do This
    }else{
        #Do this
    }
    #Everything Else
}
```

Comment: I see-- since I know I'm calling it from a loop, explicitly tell it to the function. One problem is that my function is by design a binary operator. I can probably get around that by an `options()` setting. But the bigger problem is that if I package it up for other people to use (because boy does it solve a long-ignored problem) manually telling it that it's in a loop is much less user friendly than automagically detecting loops and logging them differently than explicit calls.

Comment: Aw, come on, don't vote parent responder down folks. He might have missed the part about this being R language, but the suggestion he made _is_ relevant to my question, even if I can't do it that way because of the reasons above.

Comment: Yes i would agree it would be easier to check from within function but the only information sent when calling a function are the parameters of that function. You could try making a module that assigns a parent to a function which would then allow you to set the parent calling type but that would be just as non user friendly. using a optional parameter would be the easiest and then just put some good commenting to help other developers

Comment: @AlexMurray f13br4nd has mentioned that it's a binary operator so it's not really possible to send in other optional parameters directly.

Comment: i dont actually use r code this is more of just a psudo code thing you can figure out the rest

Comment: @JasonMorgan This is perfectly valid [tag:R] code (even if there probably are better ways of doing it)

Comment: @Andrie, the answer has been edited.  It was not R code when originally posted.

Comment: @GSee Thank you, I can now see that from the edit history. You're right, the first code certainly wasn't [tag:r]

Answer (score 0):

Oops, that was premature. Turns out that the index variable *does* persist after a `for()` loop. Darn.

<strike>Hmm! I might have it.</strike> I already have a function that replaces an arbitrary string in a function with the contents of a variable:

```
replaceincall <- function(xx,from,to){
  # from is a string, to is a name
  if(is.name(xx)){
    ifelse(as.character(xx)==from,return(to),return(xx));
  } else {
    if(is.call(xx)) {
      oo <- lapply(as.list(xx),function(yy) replaceincall(yy,from,to));
      return(as.call(oo));
    } else {
      return(xx);
    }
  }
}
```

In my overloaded `<<-` function, I also already extract a list of names from `sys.call()` that do not correspond to functions. That means they are some kind of variable. <strike>All I have to do is find the ones that are not in `ls(.GlobalEnv)` and those must be the ones that are index variables and should be replaced with their values in the log entry (using the above function)</strike>.

Now, this might catch and replace stuff besides loops... but perhaps that's a good thing because regardless of the reason a variable isn't in `.GlobalEnv`, it's still a dynamic variable and therefore someday when I'm looking through the log I'm going to wonder how to reconstruct it if I don't capture it's value right now.

Does anybody see any flaws in this reasoning?

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.